# jmeter is opening many firefox session(threads) when integrated with selenium using jar approach

Tags: selenium-rc, jmeter, junit4

I am currently using the jar of my selenium test suite to integrate with JMeter but, the problem which I am facing is that JMeter is opening the Firefox session equals to the number of threads which I specify because of that, my system gets unresponsive.

Does any one knows how to suppress multiple browser session to open on system without affecting the load testing?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal each thread open his own browser... Maybe you can use phantomJS driver but ut will use memory too... Maybe not use this way and use recording controller to record scenario an play it directly with jmeter that is the stress test way the other not test the performance... You can use chrome headless too but cost memory too.. Another solution start new thread only when first thread us finish... I think with versiin 45 of firefox (only version working with jmeter) and jmeter 3.3 firefox not possible headless... Google an phantomJS yes possible.

The best solution use recorder controller.. Record a case and play it... Jmeter will use internal browser "system" low cost to achieve it dont forget that jmeter is stress test tool... You can use to do other action but not efficiently...